# How to re-install http windows service

Tags: windows-7, windows-services

I replaced apache webserver with http(WINHTTP windows service) for use virtual hosts feature. But I was missing  http(WINHTTP windows service) which I previously removed.I  now want to  reinstall this service for use print spooler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up the `Programs and Features` item in Control Panel. On the left you'll see `Turn Windows features on or off`. Click on that.

A dialogue box called `Windows Features` appears, and inside there, you'll want to make sure that `Internet Information Services` (IIS) is checked or shaded. The `World Wide Web Service` under that option is what you're really looking for.

If you're sure this is installed, the next step is to make sure that the Web Server service is actually running. If you installed Apache, make sure it is now *disabled*, or configured for a port different to port 80 which IIS uses.

In Control Panel again, find `Administrative Tools` > `Services`, and look for `World Wide Web Publishing Service`. Make sure it is set to `Automatic`, and that it is `Started`. If it isn't started, right-click on it and click `Start`.

Assuming everything to this point is happy, it starts up and you will be able to serve web pages from IIS. If it fails, you'll need to troubleshoot. Usually IIS doesn't start if there is something else running on port 80 (e.g. Apache).

Answer (score 6):

my http windows service was disabled. to enable this service.
run this code in command line or Run

```
sc config http start= auto
```

print spool-er  service depends on http service . if http service was disabled . print spooler(print service) unable to start.

Comment: +1. This is the command line version of what I suggested, and it's a great suggestion if you don't want to go through the UI.

Comment: 2 hours of searching and following multiple suggestions with 4 restarts and this one line fixed everything. Thanks a million

Comment: @MajidTaheri Thanks for posting your answer.. it works fine to fix the issue described here http://superuser.com/questions/176520/cannot-start-service-w3svc-on-computer/ +1