# Stop services when not used

Tags: windows, performance, services, performance-tuning

My PC is installed with softwares like Visual Studio 2010, SQL Server 2008 etc.
I need these softwares very rarely, for example once in a month.

How can I improve my PC performance by stopping unwanted service, because some components of SQL is designed to run always.

I cannot uninstall and the re-install these softwares because it is very time consuming. How can I stop all services related with this kind of softwares

Comment: disable windows service may be occur many problem.  for example  http://superuser.com/questions/416712/how-to-re-install-http-windows-service

Answer (score 2):

There's no need. Services that aren't being used only affect system startup, and most of these services start on demand anyway. Basically, there's nothing you need to do. The services are already designed not to impact performance when they aren't being used.

You'll notice that the people who claim that disabling unnecessary services improves system performance never provide benchmarks to backup their claims. There's a reason for that.

> If someone tries to talk you into disabling a bunch of other services, ask them what you stand to gain. I’ll bet they can’t tell you. - [Ed Bott](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/bott/fixing-windows-vista-part-4-get-smart-about-services/448?pg=3)

This is an example of people repeating incantations that worked for others in the distance past without understanding why it was needed and therefore when it isn't needed. It's [cargo cult](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_science) IT.

Comment: So you say, installing lot and more softwares will not affect the performance. Right ?

Comment: That's debatable - I have `sqlservr.exe` using about 140MB Memory (Private Working Set)... and I've never used (nor even opened) SQL Server. *If* he is running short on memory, closing this could help.

Comment: @Bob: That doesn't affect performance. If that memory wasn't used by SQL server, it would be free. Only used memory has an affect on performance. As soon as that physical memory is needed, it will be taken from SQL server. (If you were running short on memory, those pages wouldn't be resident.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Free (unallocated) memory would be used for the disk cache, while 'used' memory would not. Increased cache space could improve performance, though not by much unless free/cached RAM was extremely low and/or the disk is extremely slow.

Comment: @Bob: Windows is smart enough to recognize when the system would benefit from a larger cache and will squeeze mapped pages and discardable pages. In general, if it's possible to do the right thing, the memory manage will do it. (Assuming he has Vista or later. XP was bad at that.)

Comment: @Rauf: A program that's just installed only takes up disk space. If it's running as a process but not actually doing anything, it will not affect performance noticeably. It will occupy some memory at least some of the time. But as soon as the OS has some better use for the memory that process is occupying, it will take the physical memory from that process and use it for something else. (If you put a memory load on a Windows system, you will see the working sets of other processes shrink. The OS is smart and understands that physical memory is a precious resource.)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use windows. Press window key to open start menu. Then search for "services". Now in the opened list look for services you don't need and turn them off. Disabling unwanted services can free up some memory space.

Comment: Right, but that's pointless since free memory has no effect on performance. Free memory is memory the system is *not* using. And if the system needed the memory, it would make it free anyway.

Comment: That's not right. If the operating system is forced to free up memory it takes time to copy the evicted pages to HDD.

Comment: In addition, having many active services slows down booting. specially heavy ones mentioned in the question.

Comment: Your first point is irrelevant. The number of pages is fixed since the services aren't active and each one only needs to be moved once. (And typically, many of them are discardable and so don't get copied anyway.) So it's less than negligible -- microscopic. Your second point is correct. You can speed up boot time by disabling services you don't use regularly or switching them to start on demand if they support that.

Comment: You cannot discard any pages! If what you say is correct then "trashing" is not a bad thing for OS.

Comment: You can discard any pages that are discardable. For example, pages that contain unmodified copies of file data are discardable (which includes DLLs and executables, a significant fraction of the memory usage on typical Windows services). Windows also has a mechanism to tell processes that the system could benefit from more free memory and processes can respond by unmapping pages and making them discardable. Microsoft-provided services tend to use this mechanism well. Third-party code may or may not.

Comment: Thrashing occurs when the working set exceeds physical memory. Services that aren't being used won't contribute to thrashing because they aren't accessing any pages. As soon as memory load gets significant, their pages will be removed from the working set. (Windows only does this when it needs to. If you put a memory load on a modern Windows system, you can actually watch other processes shrink their working sets.)